# Win 7 seems to be stuck at 16 bit colors

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, colors, 16-bit

My Windows seems to have an odd issure where some graphics seem always to been drawn in 16 bit colors, but others not (or at least i dont notice it then).

To be more specific, my Windows is set to true Color(32 bit 1920x1080) in the settings. But tho in most games and video streams only 16 bit colors are shown. You can see that in those screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy1F1.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTdo3.jpg

It doesnt depend on the displaying device, as it happens on my Samsung TV aswell as on my LG monitor. I have a MSI NVIDIA GTX 1070 Graphics card and im running Win 7 Professional 64 bit on a Intel i5 6400.

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia drivers? Which version?

Comment: Oh, yeah i forgot to mention that. I just updated it to the newest version because I tought it might help out but no change. Installer Version is "391.01-desktop-win8-win7-64bit-international-whql.exe" Device manager says Version: 23.21.13.9101 Date: 23.02.2018.
Had one from 4th quater of 2017 before.

Comment: Your screenshots show 24 bit images. Why do you think they are only 16 bit?

Comment: Oh, really? I just know 32 and 16 bit, sorry. But it should be 32, thats the point that bothers me

Comment: @DavidPostill Im sorry, i just took a look at the screenshots i posted and it seems like screenshotting the issue doesn't work. Because right now my graphics are sporadicly fine and the screenshots look "normal" to me, they looked worse (again i assume 16-Bit colors.) Next time it happens ill take a picture with my mobile and upload it..

Comment: 32 bit is 24 bit colour with 8 bit alpha channel. Alpha is transparency. 24 bit colour for captured images is normal as the alpha gets flattened down during screen drawing and what gets put out to the actual monitor is 24-bit colour RGB.

Comment: It sounds like you have a monitor issue. Those images look fine on my HDR monitor. Check your monitor cables. It is possible that low quality cables make the signal degrade and your graphics card is switching down HDMI speeds to 4:2:0 chroma sampling, which will end up looking like a "low colour" screen https://www.displayninja.com/chroma-subsampling/